# $\partial A = \emptyset \iff$ there is a map $f: X \to \Bbb R$ for which $\overline{f[A]} \cap \overline{f[X \setminus A]} = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A \subset X$. Show that the following statements are equivalent.
> \begin{align}(1) & \ \partial A = \emptyset \\ (2) & \text{ There exists a continuous map $f: X \to \Bbb R$ for which $\overline{f[A]} \cap \overline{f[X \setminus A]} = \emptyset$}\end{align}

I’ve managed to prove $(2) \to (1)$ as follows.

Since $f[\overline{A}] \subset \overline{f[A]}$ and $f[\overline{X \setminus A}] \subset  \overline{f[X \setminus A]}$ we have that $$f[\overline{A}] \cap f[\overline{X \setminus A}]  = \emptyset.$$ Due to continuity this means that $\overline{A} \cap \overline{X \setminus A} = \emptyset$, but $\overline{A} \cap \overline{X \setminus A}  = \partial A$, thus $\partial A = \emptyset$.

However I cannot get from $(1) \to (2)$. The fact that $\partial A = \emptyset \implies A$ is closed and open. How can I use this fact to show $\overline{f[A]} \cap \overline{f[X \setminus A]} = \emptyset$?

Comment: Try using a function that’s as simple as it can be. Since you know nothing about $X$ there’s a limited supply of candidates anyway. Can you write down any continuous function $f:X\to {\mathbb \R}$?

Comment: It seems that the indicator function would to the trick, but it’s not very intuitive to figure out to use that...

Answer (score 1):

For $(2) \to (1)$, the observation that $$f[\overline{A}] \cap f[\overline{X\setminus A}] = \emptyset\tag{a}$$ is correct (and uses the continuity of $f$).

Then the last observation you have to make (nothing to do with continuity): if $\partial A \neq \emptyset$ then any $p \in \partial A$ is both in $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{X\setminus A}$ and so $f(p)$ would contradict $(a)$. So $\partial A = \emptyset$ must hold.

For the other direction, use the fact that *if* $\partial A = \emptyset$ the map $f(x)=0$ if $x \in A$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x \notin A$ is continuous, because $X$ is the union of the two disjoint closed sets $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{X\setminus A}$ (the intersection is $\partial A$ which is empty) and $f$ is continuous (even constant) on both parts.

It clearly fulfills the disjoint closure condition from $(2)$.